# Broken GLX error when using Bumblebee 3.2.1 on openSUSE 13.1

Tags: opensuse, nvidia, graphics, bumblebee

**Update**

I started all over again. This time instead of the one-click button for the drivers I installed `nvidia-bumblebee`. This works slightly better because now I have my desktop effects back again. Also applications which need OpenGL are up and running again. However I still cannot run glxspheres:

```
$ optirun glxspheres
Polygons in scene: 62464
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
Visual ID of window: 0x20
[VGL] WARNING: The OpenGL rendering context obtained on X display
[VGL]    :8 is indirect, which may cause performance to suffer.                                                                                                                                                                                
[VGL]    If :8 is a local X display, then the framebuffer device                                                                                                                                                                               
[VGL]    permissions may be set incorrectly.
Context is Indirect
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 540M/PCIe/SSE2
[VGL] ERROR: in readpixels--
[VGL]    358: GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object extension not available
```

**Old**

I have installed Bumblebee 3.2.1 for openSUSE 13.1 64 bit, unfortunately it is not working properly. The discrete card is OFF as it should, however if I use optirun/primusrun I get the following error:

```
$ optirun glxspheres64
primus: fatal: broken GLX on main X display

$ primusrun glxspheres64
primus: fatal: broken GLX on main X display
```

I managed to discover that a symbolic is pointing to a non-existing shared library:

```
$ cd /usr/lib64/nvidia/xorg/modules/extensions
$ ls -l
$ libglx.so -> /usr/lib64/nvidia/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so.331.4x
```

I do not remember what the exact last digit was, so that's the reason for the trailing x. I changed the symbolic link to point to other similar (existing) shared libraries such as:

- /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
- /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/updates/extensions/libglx.so.331.79

But that did not work (even after a reboot). So I'm out of ideas. Can someone help me out? For the purpose of completeness I will now elaborate on how I installed bumblebee.

**How I installed Bumblebee**

- First I cleaned up my system using this guide:
  http://smithfarm-thebrain.blogspot.cz/2013/10/opensuse-131-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee.html
- Reboot
- Then I installed Bumblebee according to the section "Procedure" of this guide: [http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:NVIDIA_Bumblebee](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aNVIDIA_Bumblebee)
- According to that same guide I installed the NVIDIA drivers using the one-click button for "GeForce 8 and later" on: [http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:NVIDIA_drivers](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aNVIDIA_drivers)
- Reboot

**Output of verifications**

```
$ groups
users wheel video vboxusers bumblebee

# ls /proc/acpi/bbswitch
/proc/acpi/bbswitch

# cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch
0000:01:00.0 OFF

# systemctl status bumblebeed
bumblebeed.service - Bumblebee C Daemon
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bumblebeed.service; enabled)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2014-06-16 17:15:54 CEST; 31min ago
Main PID: 730 (bumblebeed)
CGroup: /system.slice/bumblebeed.service
        └─730 /usr/sbin/bumblebeed

Jun 16 17:26:21 izanagi bumblebeed[730]: [45B blob data]
Jun 16 17:26:21 izanagi bumblebeed[730]: Try '/usr/bin/mknod --help' for more information.
Jun 16 17:26:22 izanagi bumblebeed[730]: [  642.964255] [WARN][XORG] (WW) Unresolved symbol: fbGetGCPrivateKey
Jun 16 17:26:22 izanagi bumblebeed[730]: [  642.964294] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the GLX module; please check in your X
Jun 16 17:26:22 izanagi bumblebeed[730]: [  642.964301] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     log file that the GLX module has been loaded in your X
Jun 16 17:26:22 izanagi bumblebeed[730]: [  642.964307] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     server, and that the module is the NVIDIA GLX module.  If
Jun 16 17:26:22 izanagi bumblebeed[730]: [  642.964313] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     you continue to encounter problems, Please try
Jun 16 17:26:22 izanagi bumblebeed[730]: [  642.964319] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     reinstalling the NVIDIA driver.
Jun 16 17:26:22 izanagi bumblebeed[730]: [  642.964329] [WARN][XORG] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
Jun 16 17:26:22 izanagi bumblebeed[730]: [  643.080318] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

$ optirun --status
Bumblebee status: Error (3.2.1): [XORG] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `primusrun` instead

```
primusrun glxspheres
```

You should also find out, if possible, what package that link belongs to; though, I'm assuming the package is already uninstalled.  Therefore, try:

```
rm -rf /usr/lib64/nvidia/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
```

Comment: Wow thanks primusrun works! It didn't before when I installed different drivers.

Comment: I'm assuming there were some leftover files/symlinks from your previous nvidia-driver installation, which may have been responsible for tripping up the xorg-server. I'm glad it works now :D